# Copy a range and paste values in all sub sheets, we have the code for one sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

We have a google script which is working fine for one sub sheet (Sub Sheet Name - Candy), but how can we run it for all other sub sheet, Other Sub Sheet Name is Leno, Sam, Gnito, Param, Ning

In All Sub Sheet Cell in Cell D37 we have put a filter through which we are getting the value in Cell D37:M41, now we want to convert it to "Formula to Value"

Code is

```
function CopyValue() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Candy'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('D37').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('D37:M41').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('D37:M41').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setFontSize(10)
  .setFontFamily(null)
  .clearFormat()
  .setHorizontalAlignment('center')
  .setVerticalAlignment('middle');
  spreadsheet.getRange('D37:D41').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('D37').activate();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use a `for` loop or `forEach`

Below I demonstrate your code adapted with `forEach`

```js
// This function copies and pastes the ranges.
function copyRanges(sheet) {
  // Copy pasting your code here:
  sheet.getRange("D37").activate();
  sheet
    .getRange("D37:M41")
    .copyTo(
      sheet.getActiveRange(),
      SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,
      false
    );
  sheet.getRange("D37:M41").activate();
  sheet
    .getActiveRangeList()
    .clearFormat()
    .setHorizontalAlignment("center")
    .setVerticalAlignment("middle");
}

// This function selects the sheets.
function updateSheets(sheetArray = null) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();

  if (sheetArray != null) {
    sheets = sheets.filter((sheet) => {
      let name = sheet.getName();
      return sheetArray.includes(name);
    });
  }

  sheets.forEach((sheet) => {
    updateSheet(sheet);
  });
}

// RUN THIS FUNCTION
function main() {
  let sheetArray = ["Leno", "Gnito", "Ning"]; // Update with sheets you want to update.
  updateSheets(sheetArray);

  // To update all sheets call this instead
  // updateSheets();
}
```

I cleaned up what seemed to me some redundant parts of your code.

A suggestion is that you stop using active ranges, copy and paste operations and start using [`getValue`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) [`getValues`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) and [`setValue`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue) [`setValues`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues). They are much faster, more robust and flexible.

#### References

- [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)
- [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [Spreadsheet Apps Script Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)
- [`getValue`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue)
- [`getValues`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [`setValue`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)
- [`setValues`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Comment: Thanks iansedano,

can we do this on selected sub sheet, suppose we have 5 sub sheets which names are 
1. Leno 
2. Sam 
3. Gnito 
4. Param
5. Ning

and we will run the above code for Leno, Gnito, Ning